# how to calculate opposite polar coordinate for OrbitControls.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have my camera set to 100,0,100.
I am using OrbitControls.js.
The camera will always be looking at 0,0,0;

When i drag and rotate the camera i would like to know how do you calculate the exact opposite direction of the camera?
Please see the image link below for reference.
http://snag.gy/L3YhL.jpg

PS:I am asking this question because I'm not very good at trigonometry/geometry, but definitely open to learn it.

Comment: (-100,0,-100) i.e. multiply your coords by -1 (as long as y-axis is 0)

Comment: Should put as answer Gaitat :)